# Ruby Regular Expression For IP Address

Tags: ruby, regex

It doesn't work as expected. In my expectations only the second version should succeed. I would expect the same behaviour as in any other programming languages.

```
irb(main):071:0> "10.0.0.62" =~ /^10\.1*/
=> 0
irb(main):072:0> "10.0.0.62" =~ /^10\.*/
=> 0
```

I read [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html).

Comment: `*` repeats the previous token (1 in the first line, `\.` in the second line) 0 or more times. It's not the same as `*` in glob syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my expectations only the second version should succeed.

No, Since you added `*` next to 1 which means there may be a possibility of 1 occurs zero or more times, ie `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times. So the first example must return true.

`\.*` repeats the literal dot zero or more times. So this `^10\.*` regex would match `10`, `10.`, `10......`

Comment: Agreed. My bad. I was using lots of globs lately.

Comment: Do `1*` and `\.*` serve any purpose?

Comment: no,  first example expects a dot after 10 but the second one won't.